# Execute custom query when a connection is fetched from dataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, database-connection, hibernate-entitymanager

My web application runs on Tomcat 7.0 and uses Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.3 and Oracle Database.

The entityManagerFactory is configured as `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and the transactionManager is `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager`. The dataSource is defined as `org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean` and internally refers to a connection pool of type `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory`.

Each time when a connection is fetched from the pool by the entityManager, I'd like to execute a custom sql statement in that connection. It will only change a property in the Oracle session context, like so:

```
dbms_session.set_context(context, propName, propValue);
```

So no dml is done.

Each time when a connection is released back to the pool, a similar statement should be executed to clear the property value.

The property value should be fetched dynamically from the spring-security context, so I can't hardcode this into a [connection test statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907348/execute-a-sql-statement-when-a-connection-is-created).

I've also looked into [Hibernate interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864586/how-to-execute-custom-sql-code-in-every-transaction-managed-by-spring-datasource), but I've found no way to execute any sql in the same session from within an interceptor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Easy way is to just wrap the `DataSource` you get and execute the query in the `getConnection` method and also wrap the returned `Connection` and implement other query in the close method (before calling close on the delegate). A more complex solution would be to implement it using `AOP` for this.

Comment: For now we've implemented a custom subclass of `JpaTransactionManager` and inserted the extra statements into its `doCommit` method. However, this only works when working with Hibernate objects. When calling an Oracle stored procedure, the statements are executed after the stored procedure, which is too late :( Still looking for the correct solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you, will look into this.